# Where to check total circulation of ETH, creation of ETH and supply of ETH?

Tags: ether

Where can I check stats on how many ETH will there be created (what is the limit), how it will reduce in its creation, what are the caps (if any).

I understand that there isn't limited amount like in BTC, so I want to know the process of ETH supply. From what I see, this price has jumped majorly, but for a lot investors it depends how many ETH are mined each day and how will this progress in the future.